# How to prevent stack smashing on ccminer

Tags: gpu-mining, linux, error-log

I have tried everything to get mining with my Nvidia GPU on Ubuntu 16.04 using ccminer. I've tried completely purging all drivers and dependencies and building from scratch, but I still have this issue, but when I try to run I get a "stack smashing detected" error:

```
richard@motherload:~/Apps/ccminer-cryptonight$ ccminer -o stratum+tcp://monerohash.com:3333 -u 49rGPcgztcd3ULhDSiao7AZh3666xfE3LTTWwUHXeqyJ37TmvtCWtcsCRqRs794HnKT3exyvoZ6hFTYgB3CD4x7y8dXH2Xg -p x
    *** ccminer-cryptonight for nVidia GPUs by tsiv ***
 based on ccMiner by Christian Buchner and Christian H.
 based on cpuminer-multi by LucasJones
 based on pooler-cpuminer 2.3.2 (c) 2010 Jeff Garzik, 2012 pooler
    BTC donation address: 1JHDKp59t1RhHFXsTw2UQpR3F9BBz3R3cs
    DRK donation address: XrHp267JNTVdw5P3dsBpqYfgTpWnzoESPQ
    JPC donation address: Jb9hFeBgakCXvM5u27rTZoYR9j13JGmuc2
    VTC donation address: VwYsZFPb6KMeWuP4voiS9H1kqxcU9kGbsw
    XMR donation address: 
      (man these are long... single address, split on two lines)
      42uasNqYPnSaG3TwRtTeVbQ4aRY3n9jY6VXX3mfgerWt4ohD
      QLVaBPv3cYGKDXasTUVuLvhxetcuS16ynt85czQ48mbSrWX
-----------------------------------------------------------------
*** stack smashing detected ***: ccminer terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

My video card is a GeForce GTX 580 (CUDA compute 2.0). I have the latest drivers installed from Nvidia. I have tried to use the `--threads=1` flag to see if that would help, but no dice. I've also tried using CUDA 6.5 and CUDA 8.0. I am out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was accidentally using the ancient and unmaintained tsiv branch of ccminer. When I had tried to install the KlausT version, it didn't overwrite this old version.

To [solve this](https://github.com/KlausT/ccminer-cryptonight/issues/18), I ran `sudo rm /usr/bin/local/ccminer` and re-cloned the [KlausT branch of ccminer](https://github.com/KlausT/ccminer-cryptonight).